# encrypt home folder

Tags: 14.04

im still a somewhat new but kind of experienced user of linux. Ive recently installed gnome/ubuntu onto my laptop, and when i installed it i forgot to encrypt my home folder.
so is there anyway to do it through the same process that would've been done by the OS installer?, preferably through a GUI instead of terminal commands.
also, would this have any impact on anything running from within the home folder? ive installed star trek online (by means of wine unfortunately). And, id like to know ahead of time if there's going to be a slowdown effect due to the encryption. (/josh/home/Star Trek Online) should be the folder directory.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one of 2 ways.

1. Graphical - Just create a new user and encrypt your home directory.
2. Command line to actually migrate your home directory (no graphical option).

Boot to recovery mode, start a root shell

Remount / in rw

```
mount --options remount,rw /
```

Migrate

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home --user your_user
```

reboot

See also - http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/02/long-overdue-introduction-ecryptfs.html

Answer (score -1):

i don't know about encrypting the home folder other than during the install process but you can use TrueCrypt to encrypt a folder or an entire partition, though that a system partition is not recommended to be encrypted
install truecrypt like this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stefansundin/truecrypt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install truecrypt
```

Comment: i looked that up and it says its been discontinued and recommended to find an alternative solution :/. thanks though.